# Observability in API Manager - API Manager Analytics/ Dynatrace/ AppDynamics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While API Manager Analytics provide lot of detailed information from the API invocation perspective, we are also looking at integrating with a proper observability product to provide a superset of observability just compared to monitoring.

Modern day observability consist of logs, metrics, and tracing. In order to get these model observability, in my view API Manager is not sufficient.

Can we integrate API Manager with other observability platforms such as Dynatrace or AppDynamics and do we have any resources or sample implementations for the same?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 APIManager default support Jaeger and Zipkin as OOTB tracers. You can find more information on how to enable them from [1]. Rest, you can easily create a custom tracer which is also included in the above link. A similar custom implementation done with Dynatrace can be found in [2].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/traces/monitoring-with-opentracing/
[2] - https://github.com/tbrandl-dynatrace/wso2-apimanager-dynatrace

Answer (score 0):

Observability is a goad feature which can provide end-to-end observability covered things like data lineage as well. In distributed API Manager architecture, tracing a message is important to debug and observe a message path.

OpenTracing allows you to enable distributed tracing for WSO2 API Manager. OpenTracing aims to be an open, vendor-neutral standard for distributed systems instrumentation.

WSO2 API Manager supports the following types of ways to retrieve instrumented data.

- Jaeger
- Zipkin
- Log

For more details [1]
[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/traces/monitoring-with-opentracing/

Also, if you have already invested on Dynatrace or AppDynamics, you can integrate them with API Manager as wall.